# Subsetting a data set inside for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I'm trying to loop through a string vector called iter in order to subset a data frame in R. I would like to filter that data frame using i iter value in the loop and assign it to a variable using iter value i.

```
iter<- c(COD1,COD2,COD3)

    for ( i in iter) {
      assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
    }
```

The output of this command would be 3 variables which are dataframes. I'm interested in a column named mu.spline which is present in these 3 variables:

```
TestID    mu.spline   lambda.spline
COD1      0.02        3
COD1      0.03        4
COD1      0.01        1

TestID    mu.spline   lambda.spline
COD2      0.1         8
COD2      0.25        10
COD2      0.01        3

TestID    mu.spline   lambda.spline
COD3      0.12        1
COD3      0.32        8
COD3      0.22        3
```

However, If I want to obtain the column named mu.spline and assign it to a new variable from subseted variables an error occurs:

```
for ( i in iter) {
  assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
  assign(paste0(i,".mu"), i[,"mu.spline"])
}
```

Output:

```
Error in i[, "mu.spline"] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

If i try the following code, the iteration is working:

```
for ( i in iter) {
  assign(i, subset(out,TestId==paste0(i) & AddId=="Curva_F_Cor"))
  i
  assign(paste0(i,".mu"), "hi")
}
```

It seems the problem occurs when I try to obtain the column named mu.spline from each variable using i[,"mu.spline"]. I wonder why it fails beacuse i tryed this way getting columns (`COD1[,"mu.spline"]`) outside a loop and it worked...

**Edit for dput():

```
structure(list(TestId = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), .Label = c("Comb1", 
"Comb2", "COD1", "COD2", "COD3", "COD4", "COD5", 
"COD6", "COD7", "COD8", "COD9", "COD10", "COD11", 
"COD12", "COD13", "COD14", "Pat"), class = "factor"), 
    mu.spline = c(0.156373645710651, 0.128179004733465, 0.133922208832118, 
    0.0968325365246728, 0.112497378553166, 0.108787192266453, 
    0.110192954818258, 0.121005105680758, 0.0980394197157738, 
    0.138420857616108, 0.127789639429687, 0.128560390185466, 
    0.110549423439033, 0.108320566548023, 0.098918312107995, 
    0.0828284492044932, 0.104197889210497, 0.122413067260436, 
    0.100261893863431, 0.0938211089313908, 0.0950013179641027, 
    0.145680825059066, 0.139104408376977, 0.126037019624304, 
    0.126708418382696, 0.129821223842992, 0.136480998324424, 
    0.13593684872676, 0.139066913195263, 0.148222162331793, 0.1063086971118, 
    0.167178433353777, 0.0999504815546864, 0.159110219357191, 
    0.125081233896366, 0.163966026506179, 0.15029944955429, 0.116975580695436, 
    0.15276496804095, 0.155339014181045, 0.112171217970295, 0.120104234834245, 
    0.133373734309075, 0.175784287024805, 0.133626401899954, 
    0.140297143337283, 0.0863206151811713, 0.170070971923806, 
    0.152896880973888, 0.10553437562759, 0.124122727198564, 0.163571762302165, 
    0.151047108367937, 0.131416085292366, 0.152515440225195, 
    0.139308623745812, 0.146009754853497, 0.170825235429307, 
    0.147466868348918, 0.126623691613807, 0.147114348605148, 
    0.141084369853073, 0.153670399861141, 0.162948873362462, 
    0.131121302899353, 0.146421599771427, 0.135166111999851, 
    0.157495164357944, 0.126927329131488, 0.159831796004744, 
    0.146936913846553, 0.12183336770971, 0.136669798817364, 0.152333836640196, 
    0.138055091325892)), .Names = c("TestId", "mu.spline"), row.names = c("76", 
"77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", 
"88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", 
"99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", 
"108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", 
"117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", 
"126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", 
"135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", 
"144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide minimal sample data.

Comment: Added a sample of data, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally not advisable to use `assign` in R.  Yes the function is available, but its use is not recommended.  I believe the results you are looking could be generated in a much simpler manner.
The `lapply` command performs the same function as the for loops above.

```
#out<- #your dataframe of data

#define an array of string valuse
iter<-c("COD1", "COD2", "COD3")
#create a list of dataframes of the subsets
ans<-lapply(iter, function(x) {subset(out, TestId==x)})
#rename the list elements
names(ans)<-iter

#to access each subset any of the listed methods:
ans[[1]]
ans["COD1"]
ans$COD1
ans[iter[1]]
```

Comment: I read a lot about lapply() function and also about that assign wasn't a good practice. I'm pretty new to R and it was easier to figure the stuff I wanted to do using for and variable's way. This deffinetly works and avoids using iterations which resulted to fail at noncomplicated tasks.. :/ I will try to use `lapply()` in further tasks like aplying shapiro test to each of these subsets :)

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example list (`lst`) from your question, and use `do.call(rbind)` to make it into a data.frame, from which it is easy to extract the desired column.

```
str <- '
TestID    mu.spline   lambda.spline
COD1      0.02        3
COD1      0.03        4
COD1      0.01        1
COD2      0.1         8
COD2      0.25        10
COD2      0.01        3
COD3      0.12        1
COD3      0.32        8
COD3      0.22        3    '

file <- textConnection(str)

raw <- read.table(file, header = T)

lst <- split(raw,raw$TestID)

> lst
$COD1
  TestID mu.spline lambda.spline
1   COD1      0.02             3
2   COD1      0.03             4
3   COD1      0.01             1

$COD2
  TestID mu.spline lambda.spline
4   COD2      0.10             8
5   COD2      0.25            10
6   COD2      0.01             3

$COD3
  TestID mu.spline lambda.spline
7   COD3      0.12             1
8   COD3      0.32             8
9   COD3      0.22             3
```

get the column you want:

```
do.call(rbind, lst)$mu.spline
```

or access the data in a loop:

```
for(l in names(lst))
{
  assign(l,lst[[l]]$mu.spline)
}
```

Comment: I jave tried your option but its giving a numeric vector containing all values of mu.spline. what i'm trying to do is to get a numeric vector containing mu.spline values of each subset of data inside the for loop. I tried i[,"mu.spline"] inside the vector but theres soe trouble with that i which results in an error described above :(

Comment: I added an option to use the data in a `for` loop

Comment: Spliting my data according and printing desired set of mu.spline inside a loop it worrks so I tried to do `for(l in lst){assign(paste0(l,".mu"), l$mu.spline)} to try to store this values in sorted variables but each iteration R displayed the sam error in the assignment line: only the first line is used as a variable. I got a bunch of values stored which seem to be vectors

Comment: adjusted for you, with `assign` function inside the loop.

Comment: I've tried yr sugestion using the data sample and it works but when i do it with m data which is larger it gives an error like `Error in splited[[l]] : invalid subscript type 'list'` I checked if my data was a list and it is..

Comment: `assign(l,lst[[l]]$mu.spline)` but when using my data which has more than 2 columns

Comment: No clue. Can you give the output of `dput()` of a part of your data? I cannot tell what difference it has compared to the example data.

Comment: I filtered data just to get mu.spline column to make it clearer and got dput(). Post Edited to enter data i use. I have also tried with data filtered and still get the same error.

Comment: The data you present is not a list but just a dataframe. Use `raw <- structure(list(TestID = stru...   ...150"), class = "data.frame")` and then run `lst <- split(raw,raw$TestID)` and the rest of my code.